# Django - serializing multiple rows to a list

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have three tables Vertex, Edge, Graph

1. Vertex can be part of many graphs. can reoccur in the same graph.
2. Edge table denotes the edge between any two vertices in a graph.

Models

```
class Graph(models.Model):
    id = models.TextField(
        primary_key=True, null=False)
    name = models.TextField()

class Vertex(models.Model):
    id = models.TextField(
        primary_key=True, null=False)
    name = models.TextField()
    extras = models.JsonField()
 
class Edge(models.Model):
    graph = models.ForeignKey(
        "Graph", related_name="edges")
    node = models.ForeignKey(
        "Vertex", related_name="g_vertex")
    dependency = models.ForeignKey(
        "Vertex", related_name="e_vertex")
```

Serializers

```
class VertexNameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Vertex
        fields = ['name']

class VertexSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Vertex
        fields = ['name', 'extras']


class EdgeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    node = VertexSerializer()
    dependency = VertexNameSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Edge
        fields = ['node', 'dependency']


class GraphSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    edges = EdgeSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Graph
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'edges']
        depth = 3
```

GraphViewSet

```
class GraphViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Graph.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GraphSerializer
```

For the above Graph
[image: Graph g-1]

Tables:

```
+-----+--------------+
| id  |     Name     |
+-----+--------------+
| g-1 | Sample Graph |
+-----+--------------+

Vertex
+-----+------+-------+
| id  | Name | Extra |
+-----+------+-------+
| v-1 | A    | {}    |
| v-2 | B    | {}    |
| v-3 | C    | {}    |
+-----+------+-------+

Edge
+-------+------+------------+
| Graph | Node | Dependency |
+-------+------+------------+
| g-1   | v-1  | null       |
| g-1   | v-2  | null       |
| g-1   | v-3  | v-1        |
| g-1   | v-3  | v-2        |
+-------+------+------------+
```

Since i have viewsets if i do a GET call on the /graph endpoint, this is the output i get

```
{
  "id": "g-1",
  "name": "Sample Graph",
  "edges": [
    {
      "node": {
        "name": "A",
        "extras": {}
      },
      "dependency": null
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "name": "B",
        "extras": {}
      },
      "dependency": null
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "name": "C",
        "extras": {}
      },
      "dependency": {
        "name": "A"
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "name": "C",
        "extras": {}
      },
      "dependency": {
        "name": "B"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

but i want the output as

```
{
  "id": "g-1",
  "name": "Sample Graph",
  "edges": [
    {
      "node": {
        "name": "A",
        "extras": {}
      },
      "dependency": null
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "name": "B",
        "extras": {}
      },
      "dependency": null
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "name": "C",
        "extras": {}
      },
      "dependency": ["A", "B"]
    }
  ]
}
```

how should i change the serializers to get the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
class GraphSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    edges = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Graph
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'edges']

    def get_edges(self, obj):
        dependencies_raw = obj.edges.values_list('node__name', 'dependency__name')
        dependencies_mapper = {}
        for node_name, dependency_name in dependencies_raw:
            dependencies_mapper.setdefault(node_name, [])
            dependencies_mapper[node_name].append(dependency_name)

        nodes = EdgeSerializer(obj.edges.distinct('name').all(), many=True).data

        data = [
            {
                **node,
                'dependencies': dependencies_mapper.get(node['node']['name'], None)
            } for node in nodes
        ]
        return data
```

I can't test it all right now. Basically I'd make two requests instead of the default 1.

First to obtain `node name` and its dependency, and the second one for distinct nodes. Then we just glue it together.

And remove `dependency` field from `EdgeSerializer`.